# which type of request is used for the `delete` button in the REST context?

Tags: rest, http, web, http-delete

I am creating a `REST` API for the Order screen. I have methods:

```
GET /api/orders
GET /api/orders/{orderId}
```

I have some buttons on the Order page and I created few endpoints for that:

```
PATCH /api/order/buttons/mark-as-read
PATCH /api/order/buttons/change-status
```

Now I need to add the `delete` button. But I don't understand how to do that. I have 2 options:

1. `DELETE /api/orders/{orderId}` - but I should send 2 additional parameters in this request
2. `PATCH  /api/order/buttons/delete` - I can send my DTO in the body, but it is not a REST approach.

I want to understand which type of request is used for the `delete` button in the REST context?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is an entity body allowed for an HTTP DELETE request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request)

Answer (score 1):

```
PATCH /api/order/buttons/mark-as-read
PATCH /api/order/buttons/change-status
```

These are a bit strange.  PATCH is a method with remote authoring semantics; it implies that you are making a change to the resource identified by the effective target URI.

But that doesn't seem to be the case here; if you are expecting to apply the changes to the document identified by /api/orders/{orderId}, then *that* should be the target URI, not some other resource.

```
PATCH /api/orders/1
Content-Type: text/plain

Please mark this order as read.
```

```
PATCH /api/orders/1
Content-Type: text/plain

Please change the status of this order to FULFILLED
```

Of course, we don't normally use "text/plain" and statements that require a human being to interpret, but instead use a patch document format (example: [application/json-patch+json](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902)) that a machine can be taught to interpret.

---

> I want to understand which type of request is used for the delete button in the REST context?

If the semantics of "delete" belong to the `Orders` domain (for instance, if it is a button that signals a desire to *cancel* an order) then you should be using PUT or PATCH (if you are communicating by passing updated representations of the resource) or POST (if you are sending instructions that the server will interpret).

The heuristic to consider: how would you do this on a plain HTML page?  Presumably you would have a "cancel my order" form, with input controls to collect information from the user, and possibly some hidden fields.  When the user submits the form, the browser would use the form data and HTML's form processing rules to create an application/x-www-form-urlencoded representation of the information, and would then POST that information to the resource identified by the form action.

The form action could be anything; you could use /api/orders/1/cancel, analogous to your mark-as-read and change-status design; but if you can use the identifier of the order (which is to say, the resource that you are changing), then you get the advantages of standardized [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) for free.

It's normal for a single message handler, which has a single responsibility in the [transfer of documents over a network domain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m08s), ex POST /api/orders/{orderId}, to interpret the payload and select one of multiple handlers (change-status, mark-as-read, cancel) in *your* domain.

---

> you offer to use something like this: PATCH  /api/orders/{orderId} and OrderUpdatesDto as JSON string in the request body?

Sort of.

There are three dials here: which effective request URI to use, which payload to use, which method to use.

Because I would want to take advantage of cache invalidation, I'm going to look for designs that use: /api/order/{orderId} as the effective request URI, because that's the URI for the responses that I want to invalidate.

It's fine to use something like a JSON representation of an OrderUpdate message/command/DTO as the payload of the request.  But that's not really a good match for remote authoring.  So [instead of PATCH, I would use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post)

```
POST /api/orders/1 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/prs.pavel-orderupdate+json

{...}
```

But you can *instead* decide to support a remote authoring interface, meaning that the client just edits their local copy of /api/order/1 and then tells you what changes they made.

That's the case where both PUT (send back the entire document) and PATCH (send back a bunch of edits) can make sense.  If `GET /api/orders/1` returns a JSON document, then I'm going to look into whether or not I can support one of the general purpose JSON patch document formats; [JSON Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) or [JSON Merge Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396) or something along those lines.

Of course, it can be really hard to get from "changes to a document" to a message that will be meaningful to a non-anemic domain.  There are reasons that we might prefer supporting a [task based](https://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/task-based-ui/) experience, but sending a task centric DTO is not a good fit for PUT/PATCH if you *also* want caching to work the way I've described above.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I understand correctly, you offer to use something like this: `PATCH  /api/orders/{orderId}`  and OrderUpdatesDto as JSON string in the request body?

Comment: Expanded on my earlier answer - does it help?